# How do I `set <A->>=foo`?

Tags: key-bindings, set

Due to my terminal emulator, I trying to [remap `^[(key)` to `<A-(key)>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10216459/5353461) with the <kbd>></kbd> key.

How do I do a `set` for <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>></kbd>?

I'm trying to run:

```
set <A->>=foo
```

But I get:

> ```
> E846: Key code not set: <A->>=foo
> ```

If I try to escape the `>` I still get:

> ```
> E846: Key code not set: <A-\>>=foo
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following syntax to map the "alt + greater than" key combination

```
set <a-char-62>=...
```

62 being the ASCII code for `>`.  This syntax also works for maps

```
nnoremap <a-char-62>
```